# How to add image to QTextBrowser (PyQt4) using Python at a specific required point?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am doing Text mining using python.
I created a GUI using QT and transformed it into python snippet using PyQt4.
I have QTextBrowser which indicates the sentiment index of the passage.
Based on the score of the sentiment index I want to add different images into the Qtextbrowser.
Below which I have added the screenshot of my tool.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-bFVFevEa-yMUZUMnc2UWN4T00/edit?usp=sharing

Below image is the screenshot of the tool which I have created for Text mining.
At the the bottom of the right hand panel , you can see the score of sentiment of the passage.
Now I want to add the image on the highlighted square box area depending upon the score of the sentiment.

How to add the image at the particular point in the QtextBrowser ?

Answer (score 0):

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtextbrowser.html#loadResource

Example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class myTextBrowser(QtGui.QTextBrowser):
    def loadResource (self, type, name):
        return QtGui.QPixmap("test.jpg")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    a = myTextBrowser()
    a.document().setHtml("""My image :<br /><img src="test.jpg"/>""")
    a.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What is the point of reimplementing `loadResource` here? A text-browser will load images perfectly well without it.

Comment: When I use this code, My tool hangs and it doesn't responds. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import requests
from PyQt6 import QtGui, QtCore

class myTextBrowser(QtGui.QTextBrowser):
    def loadResource (self, type, name):
        pic_data = requests.get(name.url(), allow_redirects=True).content
        pixmap = QPixmap()
        pixmap.loadFromData(pic_data)
        return pixmap

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    a = myTextBrowser()
    a.setHtml("""My image :<br /><img src="img_url"/>""")
    a.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```